# what function do i use to print out a menu? the menu was created in the admin

Tags: theming, routes

i have node that i simply want to display a menu. the menu itself is a list of archived articles, and was created in the admin.

i know how customize the node to do so, page--node--11.tpl.php.

i deleted the print render $content. so now, my pseudo code would look like.

print $archive_menu;

or perhaps i need to call a function? can someone explain how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [menu_tree_all_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7) function.

E.g.

```
$tree = menu_tree_all_data('machine-name-of-menu');
//menu_tree_add_active_path($tree);
print drupal_render(menu_tree_output($tree));
```

For more info go through the function documentation.

[menu_tree_add_active_path](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!menu_block!menu_block.module/function/menu_tree_add_active_path/7) will be found here. It will be used when you want to add active trail on menu.

Comment: thanks, i tried but got an error

Comment: Call to undefined function menu_tree_add_active_path() but i will look up that function as you suggested

Comment: @TopTomato Effectively, that is not a Drupal function.